# How do I compute the forest area for different regions?

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, land-cover, region

I am currently struggling to compute the forest area of some regions. I am an absolute beginner with Google Earth Engine.
I tried it 2 different ways, mostly by copying and editing code I found.

1. Count the number of pixels with a tree cover greater than 10% (using the Hansen data)
   I thought that, I then could simply multiply by the pixel size and get the area. 
   However, I am not sure if I can do it like that. Nonetheless, here is my code:

```js
    var gfc2017 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2017_v1_5');
        var treeCover = gfc2017.select(['treecover2000']).unitScale(10, 100);

        Map.addLayer(
            treeCover,
           {palette: ['000000', '00FF00'] });

    // import the District layers as a fusion table
    var districts = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:13cHA4yautjvngKSaPywzP9Li9FVtlkJ7Dg64DQMG');
    //add districts to the map and center map
    Map.addLayer(districts);
    Map.centerObject(districts);    

    // Count the pixels with tree cover over 10 percent
    var stats = treeCover.reduceRegions({
    collection: districts,
     reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
     scale: 30
    });
    //print('count of pixels representing forest in each circle:', stats)

    print('pixels representing forest: ', stats);
```

The numbers I am getting are however, way to high. Can anybody please help me?

2. My second approach was to try using a map that has pixels of forest area, non forest area and water of the year 2010 (ID:JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF/2010)

I tried to sum the pixels, however, I am not able to just look at forest pixels. I guess it is pretty easy to do. But reading here and googling a lot has not helped yet.

My code (without the selection of only forest pixels):

```js
 // Load the image from the archive
    var farea = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF/2010')

    var treeCover = farea

    Map.addLayer(treeCover)

// import the District layers as a fusion table
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:13cHA4yautjvngKSaPywzP9Li9FVtlkJ7Dg64DQMG');
//add districts to the map and center map
Map.addLayer(districts);
Map.centerObject(districts);    

// Sum the values of forest pixels in districts.
var areaImage = farea.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Count forest pixels in districts
var stats = areaImage.reduceRegions({
collection: districts,
 reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
 scale: 30
});
```

Would be really great if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it myself by reading more on here (someone had a comparable question about tree cover) and thinking :D
For the Hansen data, this code worked for me:

```
//Select the area with tree cover greater than 10%
var treeCover = gfc2017.select(['treecover2000']);
var greater10 = treeCover.gte(10);
var treeCover_greater10 = treeCover.updateMask(greater10);
```

Apart from that it is crucial to count instead of sum as tree cover is given as a percentage.
Hope this helps someone with the same question in the future.

Comment: Can you please tell me what dataset did you use?

Comment: I think he used the Hansen Global Forest Change v1.7 (2000-2019) : https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/UMD_hansen_global_forest_change_2019_v1_7#bands